# pdfkit not working (No wkhtmltopdf executable found)

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I installed pdfkit in virtualenv but when I try to use `from_url` function I get the error:

```
IOError : No wkhtmltopdf executable found
```

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at that link?

Comment: which link @dadexix86?

Comment: The last two lines of the error you posted...

Comment: Yes I tried .. Same problem reported

Comment: But did you installed it into the same virtualenv?

Comment: yes @dadexix86 I installed in same virualenv